# Unable to form proper waveform on matlab for ensemble averaging

Tags: matlab, waveform, health-monitoring, ensemble-learning

I am trying to use matlab to ensemble average Pressure and ECG data collected from my device.Meaning I am trying to derive a common waveform from the many ECG waves that the machine churn out.

The problem I have is that sometimes the waveform generated is correct, but most of the time the waveform that is generated is not correct. I tried adjusting the sampling frequency to stretch out the waveform, but it doesnt give me a proper waveform still.

[Machine waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VawcA.jpg)

[Supposed Correct waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvL7N.jpg)

[What I always get waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf9qi.jpg)

Datafile and Rwave code is available from the link. Saved as txt file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10ZfztDWGOIrBaPvXdiJ7r5_bLSHg_ZSJ

E= ECG (Can be taken from Site A or B)
P= Pressure (Can be taken from Site A or B)

To execute the Rwave function. Key in the Command Window "Rwave(E,P,Frequency you want)

Remember to import the data as "E" for "ECG" and "P" for "Pressure"